# Drawing triangle shape background

Tags: actionscript-3

I have three Points in the array. I want to draw a triangle using this Points.

For now, I achieve to draw a border of this triangle using MoveTo() and LineTo() functions.

The problem is, I also need to draw an inner background of an area that this lines creates.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `graphics.beginFill(color);`:

```
public function astest()
{
    var verticies:Vector.<Point> = Vector.<Point>([new Point(0, 100), new Point(100, 0), new Point(100, 100)]);
    var sh:Shape = new Shape();
    addChild(sh);

    drawPolygon(sh.graphics, verticies, 0xFF0000);
}

protected function drawPolygon(graphics:Graphics, verticies:Vector.<Point>, color:uint):void
{
    graphics.beginFill(color);
    var p:Point = verticies.shift();
    graphics.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    for(var i:int = 0; i < verticies.length; i++)
    {
        p = verticies[i];
        graphics.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    }   
    graphics.endFill();
}
```